# ReactJS getting URL from a database for posting images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, image, reactjs

Hello everyone i'm kinda new to ReactJS & nodeJS as frontend & backend. So far I've been helped for some things like showing all the outputs of a table in a select form but now I'm struggling for images..

My teammate has to put images in the database but he's storing them locally into a folder with multer. So now he needs the link of the image (like "./picture.jpg") so he can just use the img src to post the image.. problem is that we can't seem to achieve an easy task, getting the url of the image and putting it into a constant.

Here's the code

```js
class Collection extends React.PureComponent {


  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      images: [],
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {


const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3004/getImages');
    const newList = await response.json();
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      ...previousState,
      images: newList,
    }));

  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          {this.state.images.map(obj => obj.image).map((image, index) => <img src={require (image)} key={index} value={image} />)}
          
       <img src={require ("./image.jpg")} class="responsive-img" />
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Collection;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

So the fetch is working and here's the return of the localhost:3004/getImages: [{"image":"./ouss.jpg"}]

the second  is working as an example. However we want to add all the images, or even just show one using the mapping.
The error we get is "cannot find module "."".

This seem really easy to do but we cannot manage to achieve it.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: img tag will fetch your image by just giving them the path or link where it is, you do not need to use require

Comment: check if the folder where you are storing your images is public, so you can access them

Comment: What line where do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the backend to verify whether multer is storing the image in a publicly accessible image, otherwise you'll not be able to access the image via the image url.

Second, I'm assuming the image url is stored in a database and comes as part of the payload when you make the get request to the api.

Then in your map function, all you need to do is to put each image in an image src, like this:

```
{this.state.images.map(image => <image key={image.id} src={image.imageSrc} />)} //where 'imageSrc' is the property you stored your imagePath in your database with.
```